# How can I use Components in a VueJS2 CDN project?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am pretty much stuck on it and I'm not even sure if what I was trying is possible. 
Here's my project if needed: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lty3rzUs1h7Rtw5tsN92WeaTBJw2fqVy

Updated:
I'm not sure how to display it any better as this is the best it gets.. Basically im passing NestedComponent into Component which is getting passed into app.js which is rendering it into the index.html. That's it, for some reason doesn't work.

```js
// "main.js" the Vue file that renders to the index.html
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { Component},
  template: '<Component/>'
})

import Component from 'Component'
```

```
// "Component.vue" that is getting passed into the above "app.js"
<template lang="html">
  <div>
    <p>{{ title }}</p>
    <h1>Hi!</h1>
    <NestedComponent/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import NestedComponent from 'NestedComponent'

export default {
  name: 'Component',
  components: {
     NestedComponent
  },
  data: {
    title: 'Hello'
  }
}
</script>
```

```
// "NestedComponent.vue" a nested component that is getting passed onto it's parent Component "Component.vue"
<template lang="html">
  <div>
    <p>{{ im a nested component }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'NestedComponent',
  components: {

  },
  data: {

  }
}
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Vue</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">{{title}}</div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/script.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure you explain what you are trying to achieve and what you have trouble with in details _in the body of your question_, rather than throwing an external link to your project code. See [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). It is also expected that if you provide some code, you make it an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the body of your question.

Comment: @ghybs Updated, hope you can see it better now

Comment: `import` statements must be **before** any procedural code. If the code in your question is meant to represent separate files, please split up the code blocks with an HTML comment (`<!-- new file -->`) or horizontal rule (`---`)

Comment: `components: { HelloWorld }` <- should that not be `components: { Component }`?

Comment: `{{ im a nested component }}` <- this is not a valid expression

Comment: Yes, my bad, it's Component, not HelloWorld anymore.

Comment: @Holiday and what about the `import` statement? It should be **before** `new Vue(...)`. What are you using to build this? Surely it's reporting these syntax errors to you

Comment: I don't know what is supposed to go where. I've been sitting through 3 days and two nights learning Vue. It's 6 am again. I came here to ask for feedback on what I did wrong and what my errors are from people that surely have more experience with Vue than I do. So, if you're gonna help, then help me, everything's in the code above, so don't torture me even more with a million question comments that lead no where

Comment: @Holiday if you are a newbie, state it. Saying that experienced people's feedback lead you no where is certainly not going to get you any better support. Sounds like you mix up so many things that you cannot even properly explain what you did and what does not work. You would probably be better starting from square one with tutorials and guides.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things that I think is causing the problem:

1. You are using `.vue` files. They require special `loaders` via
   Webpack or similar tool. They will then be converted into a normal
   `.js` file. In your case, you have a CDN version of Vue so these features will not be available to you.
2. As people have mentioned before the use of `import` and `export` is not supported by the browser natively. This again needs to run through the Webpack or similar tool.

Find similar information in the docs
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html